# image slider with thumbnail click help

Tags: jquery, slider, gallery, thumbnails

I have a slider that when you click next and previous, the images slide left or right. But I'm having trouble integrating my thumbnails, when if i want to click on a thumbnail, the image will show and then you can click next and previous.

Right now my thumbnails can be clicked, and it shows up but when I click next or previous, its stuck on the same image

I have set up a jsfiddle if someone can help me? first you can see that next and previous will switch images, but once you click on the thumbnails and try next and previous, it won't change images

http://jsfiddle.net/aQTZ9/14/

Thank you!

EDIT: Do i have to set an array or something? I'm not sure how it will know which image will be next or previous when clicking the links

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `.image` click handler, you do this:

```
$('#slides img').attr('src', rel);
```

That will set the `src` attribute of **all** the images to `rel`. So nothing is getting stuck, it just looks that way because all the images in the gallery will be the same after you click on one of the thumbnails.

Instead, you need to use the `rel` attribute to find the correct image in the gallery and then call `rightImage` or `leftImage` enough times to get it into view. Or, you could add a third function that does the same thing as multiple `rightImage` or `leftImage` calls without the intermediate steps.

Here are some hints.

1. Get rid of the `$('.thumbnail-photos').mouseover` stuff, that just ends up binding a new set of click handlers every time the mouse moves over the a thumbnail. Move click handler binding inside there to the outside before you delete it though.
2. Add `id` attributes the slide `<li>` elements to make them easier to find.
3. Replace the `rel` attributes with `data-slide` attributes, the values should match the `id` attributes` above. This makes it easy to link the thumbnails directly to their slides.
4. Now the click handler on the thumbnails can get the slide with `var $li = $('#' + $(this).data('slide'))` (or `var $li = $('#' + $(this).attr('data-slide'))` in older versions of jQuery).
5. Now that you have the right `$li`, you should be able to figure out which direction and how far you need to animate the `left` value of `$('#slides ul')`.

Comment: I'm a little stuck, I'm still kinda new to jquery. Is there anyway you can help guide me to how I can set it where it will set to find the correct image? Somehow I need to get the right li img. I can set the li to an id. But the way the jquery slider works is it slides left or right (which ever images should be next). I got the jquery script from the internet and modified it a little. But it might be this `parseInt($('#slides ul').css('left')) + item_width;` and I dont know what I have to do to this part? Thanks

Comment: @andrewliu: I've added some hints to, hopefully, point you in the right direction. The `parseInt` stuff is okay (but you should always specify the [radix](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) argument).

Comment: Thank you for the hints. I'm still stuck. I've been trying to work this out for 2 hours now. can  you explain the data()? or data-slide attributes? I just can't figure out how to show the correct image with the li id tag. I'm still a newbie at jquery.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: @andrewliu: I don't blame you for being a bit confused, that slider widget is moving the `<li>` elements around rather than just moving the `<ul>` around. Give me a bit.

Comment: shesh, that was a simple one. Now I just have to figure out how to keep the order correct. =| Thanks again

Comment: @andrewliu: A better overall design would be to use a clipping `<div>` with `overflow:hidden; position:relative`, then put the `<ul>` inside that with `position:absolute;` and adjust the `top` CSS of the `<ul>` up and down to move the slides into and out of view.